# Get a New Event Summary and Description

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to find a way to get the Summary and Description of a new Event.
I can get the attendees, conference data and event id that will be persisted when event is saved, but no reference  to Summary or Description.

Example payload passed to the 'eventOpenTrigger' and 'eventUpdateTrigger':

```
{
 "commonEventObject": {
  "platform": "WEB",
  "hostApp": "CALENDAR"
 },
 "calendar": {
  "conferenceData": {
   "conferenceSolution": {
    "key": {},
    "iconUri": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/...",
    "name": "Test"
   },
   "notes": "test",
   "parameters": {
    "addOnParameters": {}
   },
   "conferenceId": "test",
   "entryPoints": [
    {
     "uri": "https://test",
     "entryPointType": "video",
     "label": "test"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "EVENT_ID",
  "calendarId": "email@company.com",
  "organizer": {
   "email": "email@company.com"
  },
  "capabilities": {
   "canSeeAttendees": true,
   "canSetConferenceData": true,
   "canAddAttendees": true,
   "canSeeConferenceData": true
  },
  "attendees": [
   {
    "email": "email@company.com",
    "self": true,
    "displayName": "email@company.com",
    "organizer": true
   }
  ]
 },
 "hostApp": "calendar",
 "clientPlatform": "web"
}
```

When try to use Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId) to get more event details, it returns 404, which makes sense since the Event is not yet persisted. Just would be nice to be able to get the event Summary and Description at the time a user creates an event rather than having to have them reopen it again afterwards

Comment: What do you mean by `persisted`? Can you explain more in detail your workflow? Do you programmatically create an event and then query for the event details on trigger? Can you provide the code you use to create the event?

Comment: @ziganotschka - I am not programatically creating an event, user creates event via UI. I am trying to create an AddOn that adds ConferenceData to an event and I want to use the new event name and description when creating the conference, before the event is saved/persisted.

Answer (score 0):

### It's [intended behavior](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#calendar_event_object) that the calendar event object does not return you the event summary and description, see also [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/154532001)

However, if you are able to trigger the `eventOpenTrigger`, you should also be able to use the method [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) with the `eventid` the event object  returns you.

- Make sure you specify the `calendar id` and `event id` for the requets correctly. You can also test with the `Try this API` first before implementing the request into your code.
- Since  'eventOpenTrigger' and 'eventUpdateTrigger' fire when an (already saved event) is being clicked on or when the Save button is clicked when a user modifies an event - there should not be any issues with the event not being saved yet.
- The Calendar API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#404_not_found) specifies that a 404 error is means:

> The specified resource was not found. This can happen in several
> cases. Here are some examples:
>
> - when the requested resource (with the provided ID) has never existed
> - when accessing a calendar that the user can not access

So most likely you are providing the wrong calendar or event id.

Comment: Mm.. it would be nice to not have to requery for that basic info. I guess an argument might be that summary and description don't change that often

BTW eventUpdateTrigger (Manifest Trigger) does not fire when click Save for me
It seems to fire when you open the edit event screen, and then again if Conference Data or Attendees change, but not when Summary and Description change

Comment: The [documentaion](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#eventupdatetrigger) says: "A configuration for a contextual trigger that fires when a Google Calendar event is edited and saved by the user." If you think it does not work as intended, you should consider filing a bug on[Google's Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

Comment: As for having that basic infor, I agree that it would be nice, but unfortunately it is not possible now. Once again, you can file a feature request for it on Issue Tracker - if enough users indicate interest in this feature by giving it a "star" chances are that Google will eventually implement it.